# Makefile and use of $$

Tags: variables, unix, makefile

So I have a Makefile in which I have the follwoing code that I try to understand:

```
for file_exe in `find . -name "zip_exe-*"`; do \
    ./$${file_exe} -d $(UNZIP_PATH)/lib; \
done
```

As I understand this piece of code will try to find some executable zip and the extract those zip files to a locations. But what puzzles me is how `$${file_exe}` is working. Why is the double `$$` needed? I guess it has something to do with the fact that some bash commands are running from a makefile, but I can't explain to myself why the `$$` is needed and a simple `$` does not work since this command is running a sub-shell anyway.

Comment: `$$` means be interpreted as a `$` by the shell. the `$(UNZIP_PATH)` gets expanded by make before being interpreted by the shell.

Comment: @Petesh: you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Make needs to distinguish whether you want a `$` to use as introducing a make-variable reference, such as `${FOOBAR}` or as a plain $ passed on to the shell. The [make specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html) (Section Macros) says that to do the latter, you must use `$$` which is replaced by a single `$` and passed to the shell. In effect, your snippet reads as

```
for file_exe in `find . -name "zip_exe-*"`; do \
   ./${file_exe} -d some/unzip/path/lib; \
done
```

to the shell.

Style note: Iterating over file lists created by backticks is considered bad style, since it may overflow the ARG_MAX limit. Better to read the file names one-by-one with

```
find . -name "zip_exe-*" | \
while read -r file_exe; do \
   ./${file_exe} -d some/unzip/path/lib; \
done
```