# Using jq to extract information about dependencies from package.json

Tags: json, node.js, bash, makefile, jq

So I am trying to run a jq command inside a makefile to link some dependencies, and I do not understand what the line inside the do-done does. If using only echo "$$dep" I understand what's going on, but when using the full line of code ([ -f "$$dep/package.json" ] && echo "$$dep";) I seem to be lost.  Does anyone have any idea? Thanks.

```
jq -r '.dependencies,.devDependencies|keys[]' $< | while read -r dep; do \
    [ -f "$$dep/package.json" ] && echo "$$dep"; \
done | (piping forward)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is in a `makefile`, there are two things that need to be understood.  First, to understand the "$$" variable (`$$dep`), see this stackoverflow question:

[Makefile and use of $$](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589957/makefile-and-use-of)

Second, to understand the ... in `do ... done`, remember that this is essentially equivalent to a shell conditional of the form:

```
if [ -f _ ] ; then echo _ ; fi
```

For details about the test, see e.g. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest

Comment: So here the `[ -f "$$dep/package. part]` is checking if that file exists ?